# Getting a file not found

Tags: html, extjs

I am following this small tutorial:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#/guide/application_architecture

I have used the exact same file structure, but when I add the controller section of the tutorial (to my app.js), where the code says:

```
`Ext.application({
    ...

    controllers: [
        'Users'
    ],

    ...
});
```

I get the error shown on the attached image. The system is looking for the controller folder the wrong place. Instead of looking for the file in the following path:

`accountmanager/app/controller/Users.js`

it looks in:

```
accountmanager/app/ext-4/app/controller/Users.js
```

So looking at the tutorial I'm following, the place that causes the trouble, is the section "Defining a controller"

I'm not sure what I have done wrong, I've starred myself blind for an hour now. Here is the index.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Account Manager</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/ext-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Note the slight difference in the html. Fx. I have only changed the js src reference, since the one in the tutorial causes a 404

Can anyone help out. I'd be grateful.
Thanks in advance

In case you wanna see the app.js code as well:

```
Ext.application({
requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
name: 'AM',

controllers: [
    'Users'
],

appFolder: 'app',

launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Users',
                html : 'List of users will go here'
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

});

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your app.'s and index.html files is located in the wrong place.
Put it in the root account manager directory